# Tkinter problem making 30 degree angle multiple times

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem https://prnt.sc/1znuffv with `tkinter`, I need it to reach from 0 to 180 degrees with making "checkpoint" every 30 degrees, I got help on this site to successfully done to reach 0-180 and back but cannot make it 30 by 30.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.resizable(0, 0)

s = 0
def menjajKanvas(arc):
global s
if s < 180:
    s+=1
    c.itemconfig(arc,extent=s,fill="red")
    root.after(10,menjajKanvas,arc)
else:
    shrink_arc(arc)
def shrink_arc(arc):
global s
if s >= 0:
    s-=1
    c.itemconfig(arc,extent=s,fill="red")
    root.after(10,shrink_arc,arc)
else:
    root.after(10,menjajKanvas,arc)

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=250, width=300, bg="blue")
c.pack()
arc = c.create_arc(10,50,240,210,
               extent=150,
               outline="red",
               fill='red',
               tags=("arc",))
menjajKanvas(arc)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does *"checkpoint" every 30 degrees* mean? What happens on this checkpoint and why do you need help ?

Comment: Checkpoint as animation should stop at 30 degrees for a second and continue to 60 degrees etc... I am doing a school project and I got stuck on this assignment.

Comment: Please note there are some term to ask [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variable delay in your function calls issued via `tk.after`:

something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def menjajKanvas(arc):
    global s
    if s < 180:
        s += 1
        c.itemconfig(arc, extent=s,f ill="red")
        delay = 10 if s % 30 else 1000
        root.after(delay, menjajKanvas, arc)
    else:
        root.after(1000, shrink_arc, arc)


def shrink_arc(arc):
    global s
    if s >= 0:
        s -= 1
        c.itemconfig(arc, extent=s, fill="red")
        delay = 10 if s % 30 else 1000
        root.after(delay, shrink_arc, arc)
    else:
        root.after(1000, menjajKanvas, arc)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x800")
    root.resizable(0, 0)

    s = 0

    c = tk.Canvas(root, height=250, width=300, bg="blue")
    c.pack()
    
    arc = c.create_arc(
        10, 50, 240, 210,
        extent=150,
        outline="red",
        fill='red',
        tags=("arc",))
    
    menjajKanvas(arc)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

You can avoid repeated code in the two functions `menjajKanvas`, and `shrink_arc` with the following new function `increment_arc` described hereunder: However, it makes it more difficult to "get it right" for beginners, and is also maybe less readable for the same reasons.

```
def increment_arc(arc, increment=-1):
    global s
    if s % 30 != 0:
        delay = 10     # sets short delay if arc not a multiple of 30
    else:
        delay = 1000   # otherwise sets a longer delay
        if s == 0 or s == 180:  # reverse the action when we reach 0, or 180
            increment = - increment
    s += increment
    c.itemconfig(arc, extent=s, fill="red")
    root.after(delay, increment_arc, arc, increment)
```

and replace the initial call (`menjajKanvas(arc)`) with `root.after(10, increment_arc, arc)`

Comment: Yess, exactly what I was looking for! delay = 10 if s % 30 else 1000 Can you explain this line of code?

Comment: @dcipko sets `delay` to `10` if `s` is not divisible by 30 (i.e. division has a remainder) else (i.e. `s` divided by 30 doesn't have any remainder) sets `delay` to `1000` (note: `0` is a falsy value, any other integer value is truthy)